# How to delete duplicates of an item from a slice?

Tags: go

I'm writing a command line tool that will delete peers from a text file.

This is the text file. Its reference in code is cfg.Bootstrap

```
 "Bootstrap": [
{
  "Address": "/ip4/162.243.139.64/tcp/5001",
  "PeerID": "QmXZPT1SLcczjNSLnSCsQBWwbosKjrDRo122Ys8ajKoQXQ"
},
{
  "Address": "/ip4/162.243.139.64/tcp/5001",
  "PeerID": "QmXZPT1SLcczjNSLnSCsQBWwbosKjrDRo122Ys8ajKoQXA"
},
{
  "Address": "/ip4/162.243.139.64/tcp/5001",
  "PeerID": "QmXZPT1SLcczjNSLnSCsQBWwbosKjrDRo122Ys8ajKoQXQ"
},
{
  "Address": "/ip4/162.243.139.64/tcp/5001",
  "PeerID": "QmXZPT1SLcczjNSLnSCsQBWwbosKjrDRo122Ys8ajKoQXA"
}
```

]

The peer object is created using a user supplied PeerID and Address. It looks like this

```
peer := config.BootstrapPeer{
                Address: address,
                PeerID:  pID,
            }
```

The goal is to remove all peers cfg.Bootstrap that contain the user supplied Address and PeerID

```
   //iterate through the list of peers multiple times so that we delete all matches
   for i := range cfg.Bootstrap {

            //iterate through the list of peers
            for i, val := range cfg.Bootstrap {

                //if the user supplied PeerID and Address match a Peer object in cfg.Bootstrap..
                if(val.PeerID == peer.PeerID && val.Address == peer.Address) {

                //remove that element 
                    cfg.Bootstrap = append(cfg.Bootstrap[:i], cfg.Bootstrap[i+1:]...)
                }

            }

                fmt.Println(i)

    }
```

This works UNLESS the last peer in cfg.Bootstrap has a duplicate. If it has a duplicate then Go panics with

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
```

I need to make it so the user can delete all copies of a peer that include the last peer. Any ideas?

Comment: They have to be ordered?

Comment: Also: https://gist.github.com/alioygur/16c66b4249cb42715091fe010eec7e33 and https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/5ia523/idiomatic_way_to_remove_duplicates_in_a_slice/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic idea is to copy values != to peer to the beginning of the slice and trim the excess when done.

```
i := 0
for _, v := range cfg.Bootstrap {
   if v.PeerId == peer.PeerId && v.Address == peer.Address {
      continue
   }
   cfg.Bootstrap[i] = v
   i++
}
cfg.Bootstrap = cfg.Bootstrap[:i]
```

Comment: what is the variable 'k'? Never defined

Comment: This doesn't take into account the user supplied peer type. My fault, i should've added an example. Added. I'm comparing values that the user supplies with the bootstrap type.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (if you have the option) is to first sort, then remove duplicates. Eg with strings;

```
strs = []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "b", "a", "e", "e", "d"}
sort.Strings(strs)

var last string
first_item := true
dedupped := []string{}
for _, s := range strs {
    if first_item {
        dedupped = append(dedupped, s)
        first_item = false
    } else {
        if s != last {
            dedupped = append(dedupped, s)
        }
    }
    last = s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marshal your struct into json and then stringify

```
data, _ := json.Marshal(yourStruct)
dup := make(map[string]bool)
dup[string(data)] = true
```

Now use this dup to filter out duplicates